# Ruby Imap OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, openssl, imap, redmine

I am trying to use IMAP and it does not work.
I tried the same with 'https' and it worked.

---

```
require 'net/imap' 
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Net::IMAP.new("xxx", 993, true).login("redmine", "redmine")
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1439:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1439:in `start_tls_session'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1036:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

---

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
gem -v 1.8.24
```

This is similar to: https://www.chiliproject.org/boards/1/topics/2076

---

```
openssl s_client -connect klevas.mif.vu.lt:imaps
```

shows that the certificate expired. However, on another system, where 
Ruby and Gem are the same, the IMAP connection works.

Comment: Why did you tag this with "redmine"? Are you trying to run this inside Redmine and it's failing, or are you trying to run from the command-line?

Comment: I was trying to fetch mail with imap into redmine and I got an error. After that I tested with irb and the output you can see above. The error is the same.

Comment: OK. As long as you triangulated the error outside Redmine. Sometimes (too often) people don't and then find out the problem is in the editor/IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
imap = Net::IMAP.new('xxx', {:ssl => {:verify_mode => 0 }})

Comment: reading net/imap.rb you find the last option on initialize is verify=true, but even setting it to false doesn't work. Your solution worked. You can also say: `{:ssl => {:verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}}`

Answer (score 3):

If we are discussing redmine here the following was helpful.

In lib/redmine/imap.rb on line 29 there was a call

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(host, port, ssl)
```

according to the information learned from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb

```
    def initialize(host, port_or_options = {},
               usessl = false, certs = nil, verify = true)
```

I changed it to

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(host, port, ssl, nil, false)
```

and the error was gone

Comment: i would prefer to config that somewhere instead of modifying application code but it's the only solution which seems to work for me.